# How do you call a member function in a member function outside of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

My class is defined in my header file, and in my .cpp file I have:

```
bool Card::foo(const std::string &trump) const {...}

bool Card::bar(const std::string &trump) const {
     bool oof = foo(const std::string &trump); 
}
```

This is not working for some reason. XCode is giving an error: Expected Expression. The same goes when I try:

```
bool oof = Card::foo(const std::string &trump);
bool oof = foo(const std::string &trump) const;
```

Comment: `bool oof = foo(trump);` You are making it way too complicated.

Comment: Why are const std::string not included?

Comment: Why should they be?

Comment: Oh I see. I misremembered and assumed that they were included. Thank you

Comment: Just one more question, I had assumed you need the & to pass by reference. Is it not needed since the function calling it already receives the input by reference?

Comment: You need the ampersand in the function *declaration* to pass by reference - not at every call site.

Comment: @Goldname Same reason you can write `printf("%d", 5);` and not `printf(const char *"%d", int 5);`. The types are *never* included when you call a function.

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
bool Card::foo(const std::string &trump) const {...}

bool Card::bar(const std::string &trump) const {
     bool oof = foo(trump); 
}
```

Any of the expression below:

```
bool oof = foo(const std::string &trump);
bool oof = Card::foo(const std::string &trump);
bool oof = foo(const std::string &trump) const;
```

would redefine the `trump` since

```
bool Card::bar(const std::string &trump) const
```

has already defined it.

Answer (score 0):

The type information is not required/allowed when calling foo (the const std::string part) because the language doesnt work this way. The function declaration will need it, but do not include the type when calling it. Look at Igor's example.